# How to Fetch data from one to many relationship mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

My code:

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, images.image_url

FROM tmdb_movies

JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,images.image_url");

 // Then fire it up
 $stmt->execute();
 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you run through this array in many ways, for example
 for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){

 echo'
  '.$result[$x]["movie_title"].' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>
  ';

}
```

> Example: How it Echo Data

```
// SOME Stuff Here
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
// SOME Stuff Here
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE// SOME Stuff Here
The Dark Knight: - <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/>
// MORE STUFF HERE
```

> How I Want It to echo data

```
// Some Stuff Here
The Dark Knight -  <img src="sdfsdfds.jpg"/> <img src="fdfgfdd.jpg"/> <img src="sdfs.jpg"/>
// More Stuff Here
```

I am using an One To Many Relationship SQL table, Two tables:

tmdb_movies and images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options

1. Condition in For Loop

   ```
   for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x < $n; $x++){
   {
       If ($x == 0 )
          {then echo $result[$x]["movie_title"];}
       echo ' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>';
   }
   ```
2. Group_concat

   ```
   SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title, Group_concat(images.image_url, ', ')
   FROM tmdb_movies
   JOIN images ON images.images_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id
   GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title,images.image_url;
   ```

The above will give you data in a single record, with comma separated values, which you can split and then create the  tags

I would go for the first option though

Comment: Both answers will not work. 

!.) If i go with 1st answer, I cannot add other stuff which i mentioned in the 1st question.

2.) If i go with 2nd answer, the image url will not work

Comment: If your **other stuff** is not dependent on your `FOR LOOP`, I don't see, why it will not work.
if you go by the 2nd option, why cant you do a split on `,` and loop over it to create the `img` tags.

Comment: Because it will be like <img src="example.com/xyz.jpg, abc.jpg, dfg.jpg"/> And let me tell you why the 1st option will not work, give me 2 mins

Comment: Please read my answer again, I said, you will get a single record with comma separated values, which you can split and then create the tags.

Comment: How i applied your 1st answer in the code: 
`If ($x == 0 ) 
{ // do some stuff }
    echo ' - <img src="'.$result[$x]["image_url"].'"/>';


if ($x == 0 )
{ do some more stuff}`

Comment: Result of 1st answer:  `//  <do some stuff>  <only 1 img tag here> // <do some more stuff here>  <all image tag here leaving 1st>`

Comment: In your 2nd answer: `Group_concat(images.image_url, ', ')` i should give it a name right? like 

`Group_concat(images.image_url, ', ') as image_url`

If yes, then it the result is like `img src="example.com/xyz.jpg, abc.jpg, dfg.jpg"/>`

If no, then it will give error (undefined variable image_url)

Comment: Is it possible to store those values in an array just after the start of forloop, and echo the array in between???

Comment: @JohnDoo for the second option, for 'do some more stuff', can you not put `if ($x == n)` so it only runs for the last record

Comment: @JohnDoo yes, value can be split and saved in an array.

Comment: I did ($x == $n) and added `=` here `for($x=0, $n=count($result); $x <=$n; $x++)`

Comment: Worked, but it will only work, if their is only 1 record.

Comment: Can you tell me the array answer?  I have some idea, how to do it with array, use `foreach` to retrive all data, and echo the array inside image tag. But i don't know syntax's

Comment: @JohnDoo - https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp will help you create array from string. Can you update your question with what you have tried, and I can update my answer as well with more information